# Correct way to Include Main Project in Build Path of library project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, android-service

I have two Projects , A(main project) and B(library project). B is included in the build path of A. I have to start few activities of B from some activities of A. This works fine until recently, I had to Start an Activity of A from an Activity of B.

To do that, I tried Adding A to the build path of B, but what this does , is, run the building process in an endless Loop.So, apparently , this is not the correct way to achieve what I want.

My question is, How do I access classes of a Main Project from a Library that is Included in the Main Project?

Comment: Something's wrong here. When a library project need to access something that is not in the library, you should actually put it into the library project instead of going through all the hassle.

Comment: okay. So what I want to achieve is not possible ?

Comment: To answer your question, it is possible. You can obtain the class by using reflection and call `startActivity` with it. However, please note that your code can break easily in the future because it will still compiles, but only throws error at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the activitys `.class` instance as a parameter to B.
Then you can start it with `StartActivity(context , class)`.

Comment: Not only activities, there are other classes as well. Maybe its possible to start an activity like that, but your solution is only valid for activities. Also, i want to send 'things' to A as well. Sending one way is working

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is one way to do it but it is not good enough. One possible way is to make the activity in library project abstract:

Activity in Project B (Library proejct)

```
public abstract class LibraryActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up activity
        // Suppose you want to start the activity when a button is clicked
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startOtherActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    public abstract void startOtherActivity();
}
```

Implement the abstract function in your main project:

```
public class LibraryActivityImpl extends LibraryActivity {
    @Override
    public void startOtherActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainProjectActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Now in your main project, start `LibraryActivityImpl` instead of `LibraryActivity`.

This way, you do not need to worry about weird access to classes that are unknown to your library project.